# 404 error on entry template in dev tools, but layout template loads

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I created a Shop page here: https://www.intermountaincleaning.net/shop/products/diamond-magic. The rest of the site is just static HTML (not Craft), and the Shop page is in a Shop folder within the public_html for the site.

Craft is pulling in the correct _layout file, and it's including the _nav and _footer, but if you open dev tools there's a 404 error on the products/_product template.

I'm staging the site here, and it's working just fine with the same templates: http://diamondmagic.jonathanweedin.com/shop/products/diamond-magic.

I can't figure out why Craft isn't pulling in the products/_product template. Attaching screenshots of my CP area, Craft folder, and public_html folder.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thank you!

[image: CP area of Craft Commerce]

[image: Craft folder on the server]

[image: public_html folder on the server]

**config/general.php**

```
<?php
    return array(
        'siteUrl' => 'intermountaincleaning.net',
        'environmentVariables' => array(
            'baseUrl' => 'intermountaincleaning.net'
        ),
        'defaultWeekStartDay' => 0,
        'enableCsrfProtection' => true,
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'auto',
        'cpTrigger' => '***********', // I'm ommitting this from StackExchange
        'devMode' => true,
        'tokenParam' => 'paypalexpress',
    );
```

Comment: Can you post your config/general.php code?

Comment: <?php

    return array(

     
     'siteUrl' => 'https://www.intermountaincleaning.net/',

 
     'environmentVariables' => array(
  'baseUrl' => 'https://www.intermountaincleaning.net/'
 ),

 
     'defaultWeekStartDay' => 0,

     'enableCsrfProtection' => true,

 
     'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'auto',

 
     'cpTrigger' => '***********', // I'm ommitting this from StackExchange

 
     'devMode' => true,

     'tokenParam' => 'paypalexpress',

    );

Comment: Is the config file exactly the same for live and staging?

Comment: @SimonKuran Yes, except for the siteUrl and baseUrl variables.

Comment: Hmm, I’m afraid I’m out of ideas. If it was me I’d try to break it in predictable ways to learn what’s going on. Try outputting ‘{{ dump(entry.title) }}’ to see if you’re loading an entry correctly.